# Getting an Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App in angularjs + karma + jasmine project

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We have a huge project with multiple controllers, factories,configs etc and recently i started to integrate karma+ jasmine to write unit test cases. However I get the above error. I read multiple solutions and injected the module in multiple ways but still get similar or multiple errors.

I want to test my factories, controllers, config but even following multiple tutorials didn't fixed my issue and I dont understand it either.

Can someone help?

app.js

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies','ngMaterial', 'infinite-scroll','ui.multiselect']);

App.factory("LS", ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    setData: function(key, val) {
      $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.setItem(key, val);
      return this;
    },
    getData: function(obj) {
      return $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.getItem(obj);
    }
  };
}]);
```

app.spec.js

```
describe('LS factory', function() {
  var  LS;

  beforeEach(module('App'));

  beforeEach(inject(function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['App']);
    LS = $injector.get('LS');
  }));

  it('has a dummy spec to test 2 + 2', function() {
    expect(2+2).toEqual(4);
  });

});
```

karma.conf.js:

```
files: [
    './node_modules/angular/angular.js',    
    './node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js',  // angular
    './node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js',
    './node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.js',
    './node_modules/ng-infinite-scroll/build/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js',
    './assets/lib/js/multiselect.js',
    './node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js', // ui-router
    './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    './node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
    './node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js',
    './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    './node_modules/moment/moment.js',
    './node_modules/lodash/lodash.js',
    './node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js',
    './node_modules/c3/c3.js',
    './app.js',
    './assets/common/*.js',
    './assets/configs/*.js',
    './assets/lib/adb/*.js',
    './admin-portal/*/*.js',
    './advertiser-portal/*/*.js',
    './publisher-portal/*/*.js',
    './app.spec.js'
    ],
```

I included all the files in karma.conf.js but still I get the following error:

```
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Linux 0.0.0) LS factory has a dummy spec to test 2 + 2 FAILED
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
        at <Jasmine>
        at node_modules/angular/angular.js:125:12
        at node_modules/angular/angular.js:5034:15
        at forEach (node_modules/angular/angular.js:418:20)
        at loadModules (node_modules/angular/angular.js:4994:5)
        at Object.createInjector [as injector] (node_modules/angular/angular.js:4911:19)
        at UserContext.WorkFn (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3181:52)
        at <Jasmine>
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.025 secs / 0.018 secs)
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Im using angular `1.6.10` and karma `2.0.2`!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently one of the dependencies I imported `ui.multiselect` is causing the error.

- I removed all the dependencies and run `karma test`
- So I started checking it by adding one after the other dependency

Finally found the issue is with one of the dependency and removed it. All the test cases are working fine now.